# python - matrix of zeros with X shaped ones in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

The code below returns a matrix that is filled with zeros, and both diagonals are ones, which creates an X shape. I want to make a one-liner for the code between the lines, anybody knows how to do that?

```
def mat(size):
# --------------------------------
m = np.zeros((size, size))
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if i == j:
            m[i, j] = 1

for i in range(size):
    m[i, size - i - 1] = 1
# --------------------------------
return m
```

What i have come up with is the code below, but that's 2 lines. The reason for  `m[m > 1] = 1` is when the size is an odd number the middle number becomes 2.

```
def mat(size):
    m = np.eye(size) + np.flip(np.eye(size), axis=1)
    m[m > 1] = 1
    return m
```

example matrix:

```
[[1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner? Your code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
def mat(size):
    return np.minimum(np.eye(size)+np.eye(size)[::-1], 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.bool_`:

```
def mat(size):
    return 1 * np.bool_(np.eye(size) + np.flip(np.eye(size), 1))
```

**OR**, *proposed by user3483203*

```
def mat(size):
    return (np.eye(5) + np.flip(np.eye(5), axis=1) > 0).view('i1')
```

Output:

```
>>> mat(5)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Rather than have to multiply you can just view the result: `(np.eye(5) + np.flip(np.eye(5), axis=1) > 0).view('i1')`

Comment: Yes thank you, another solution i found: `return np.logical_or(np.eye(size), np.flip(np.eye(size), axis=1))` if it helps anyone

Comment: @user3483203. I updated my answer with your solution.